# iOS Swift UIBezierPath CAShapeLayer fillColor with animation

Tags: swift, svg, uibezierpath

[image]

This is a Chinese word "夜". The word's outline build by `UIBezierPath` and `CAShapeLayer`.

like that:

[image]

I want to know, How to fill the word background color with the animation that like no.1 picture.

I know the word's `medians` position.

Do you have any idea? thanks.

some references:

- https://github.com/chanind/hanzi-writer/blob/master/data/%E4%BB%B6.json
- https://github.com/chanind/hanzi-writer

=== Update

```
let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
anim.fromValue = 0.0
anim.toValue = 1.0
```

That's not my want. @LouFranco

[image]

Comment: some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365732/how-to-animate-a-human-written-stroke-using-swift-ios?rq=1 -- the easy (and probably not good enough answer) is to animate strokeEnd from 0->1 on the CAShapeLayer. That simulates drawing the path

Comment: @LouFranco thanks your ideas, this is outline-based fonts not stroke-based fonts, so I can't use `strokeEnd`

Comment: I know this question is old, but could you solve that problem? I'm trying to animate chinese characters as well in the same way and don't know how to do it.